# In Angular 4, how to dynamically set min date and max date in date picker?

Tags: html, angular

I am  trying to show disable past dates from current date, meaning user should not select past date from date picker.

Below is the code I am using to set min date in Datepicker

Component.html

```
<input type="text" formControlName="eventStart" [(ngModel)]="event_start" class="form-control pull-right" 
  id="event_start" required placeholder='{{ "EVENT.FORM.START_DATE"  | translate }}'>

  <input type="text" formControlName="eventEnd" [(ngModel)]="event_end"  class="form-control pull-right" 
id="event_end" placeholder='{{ "EVENT.FORM.END_DATE"  | translate }}'>
```

Component.ts

```
this.datePicker = jQuery('#event_start').datepicker({
      autoclose: true,
      orientation: 'left bottom',
    });
this.datePicker = jQuery('#event_end').datepicker({   
          autoclose: true,
          orientation: 'left bottom',        
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `this.datePicker` twice:

1. `jQuery('#event_start')`
2. `jQuery('#event_end')`

I suggest you to refactor your code like this:

```
const datePickerConfig = {
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: 'left bottom',
};

this.startDatePicker = document.querySelector('#event_start').datepicker(datePickerConfig);
this.endDatePicker = document.querySelector('#event_end').datepicker(datePickerConfig);
```

In order to help you efficiently, please tell which date picker library you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngb-datepicker from angular bootstrap.
Modify your **component.ts** in following way,

```
now: Date = new Date();
minDate: any;
maxDate: any;

//If you want to disable past dates from current date, you can set mindate to current date.

this.minDate = { year: this.now.getFullYear(), month: this.now.getMonth() + 1, day: this.now.getDate() };

//If you want to show upcoming 50 years in dropdown, you can set maxdate like,

this.maxDate = { year: this.now.getFullYear() + 50, month: 1, day: 1 };
```

In your **component.html**,

```
<input id="event" name="event" [(ngModel)]="model" (click)="event.toggle()" #event="ngbDatepicker" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" ngbDatepicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kishoreaoe I got a way Forward.

I am Using Angular 6 and ng-Bootstrap .

I require to Set Min Date as today and Max-Date will be 1 year from today.

> ***datecomponent.component.ts***

```
import {NgbDateStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

> **Min Date Logic**

```
now: Date=new Date();

  minDate :NgbDateStruct = { year: this.now.getFullYear(), month: this.now.getMonth() + 1, day: this.now.getDate() };
```

> **Max Date Logic**

```
  maxDate :NgbDateStruct={year: this.now.getFullYear()+1, month: this.now.getMonth()+1, day: this.now.getDate()}
```

> ***datecomponent.component.html***

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control restricttextboxsize removeBorderright" placeholder="{{Initialdate | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}" name="dpStartDate"
              [(ngModel)]="modelStartDate" ngbDatepicker #dStartDate="ngbDatepicker" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate">
            <div class="input-group-append dateborder">
              <img src={{calendarImageinstance.standardimage}} class="pqestartdate grayscale" (click)="dStartDate.toggle()" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```